# Find recently added files with git

Tags: git

I want to get a list of the most recently added files using git.  Is there any sane way to do this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`git whatchanged --diff-filter=A` displays commits that added files, and the files they added, newest first.

Comment: `git whatchanged` is a bit of an anachronism, you can use `git log --diff-filter=A --stat` or  `git log --diff-filter=A --numstat --pretty='COMMIT: %H %cd'` for something more machine readable.

Comment: Thanks @TerryBrown. It looks like `git` officially recommends `git log` over `git whatchanged` as well. See the notes at the end of my answer I just added here: https://superuser.com/a/1636160/425838.

Answer (score 5):

See [@Dave Vandervies's answer](https://superuser.com/a/117652/425838) as well.

#### 1. See a log of only `A`dded files:

```bash
git whatchanged --diff-filter=A

# [preferred] OR, very similar, but slightly cleaner/less verbose file information
git log --name-status --diff-filter=A
```

#### 2. See a log of both `A`dded AND `M`odified files:

If you want to see also modified files, use instead `AM`:

```bash
git whatchanged --diff-filter=AM

# [preferred] OR, very similar, but slightly cleaner/less verbose file information
git log --name-status --diff-filter=AM
```

#### 3. To see a log of ANY and ALL types of changes, use the default:

```bash
git whatchanged

# [preferred] OR, very similar, but slightly cleaner/less verbose file information
git log --name-status
```

**Other options include the following** (from `man git diff`, search for `--diff-filter=`):

> ```bash
> --diff-filter=[(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)...[*]]
>     Select only files that are Added (A), Copied (C),
>     Deleted (D), Modified (M), Renamed (R), have their
>     type (i.e. regular file, symlink, submodule, ...)
>     changed (T), are Unmerged (U), are Unknown (X), or
>     have had their pairing Broken (B). Any combination
>     of the filter characters (including none) can be
>     used. When * (All-or-none) is added to the
>     combination, all paths are selected if there is any
>     file that matches other criteria in the comparison;
>     if there is no file that matches other criteria,
>     nothing is selected.
>         
>     Also, these upper-case letters can be downcased to
>     exclude. E.g.  --diff-filter=ad excludes added and
>     deleted paths.
>         
>     Note that not all diffs can feature all types. For
>     instance, diffs from the index to the working tree
>     can never have Added entries (because the set of
>     paths included in the diff is limited by what is in
>     the index). Similarly, copied and renamed entries
>     cannot appear if detection for those types is
>     disabled.
> ```

#### 4. Optionally specify a branch name or commit hash:

Note that for all the commands above, you can optionally also specify a branch name or commit hash. Ex:

```bash
git whatchanged commit_hash

# [preferred] OR, very similar, but slightly cleaner/less verbose file information
git log --name-status commit_hash
```

#### 5. To see just a single list (NOT a multi-entry log) of changed files, with their `M`odified/`A`dded/etc. status:

```bash
git diff --name-status commit_hash

# OR, name only (no status character)
git diff --name-only commit_hash
```

#### NOTES: `git whatchanged` vs `git log`:

`git` officially recommends `git log` over `git whatchanged`. They say `git whatchanged` exists "primarily for historical reasons." See `man git whatchanged`:

> ```bash
> DESCRIPTION
>        Shows commit logs and diff output each commit introduces.
>
>        New users are encouraged to use git-log(1) instead. The whatchanged
>        command is essentially the same as git-log(1) but defaults to show
>        the raw format diff output and to skip merges.
>
>        The command is kept primarily for historical reasons; fingers of
>        many people who learned Git long before git log was invented by
>        reading Linux kernel mailing list are trained to type it.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
git diff --diff-filter=A --name-only HEAD
```

You could try this, `--diff-filter=A` is for files that are added and not committed yet. Refer [diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) manual page for more details.
You could also try out [ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) as per your requirement. Hope this helps!